# Android - Socket client communication works on Emulator but 'IOException' occurs on phone using VPN .

Tags: java, android, sockets

The Socket client communication works on Emulator but 'IOException' occurs on phone by using VPN to connect to the Socket Server which is running on a Windows 7 PC.

The VPN network is established successfully in phone, and even some 'PING' tools installed in the phone does ping to the PC IP where the Socket Server program is running.

The part of the android code where this error is seen is as follows.

```
class CreateSocketClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress server_addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.51.100.100");
            socket = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress inetsocketaddress = new InetSocketAddress(server_addr, 9900);
            socket.connect(inetsocketaddress, 5000);
            Log.d("debug", "Connected to Socket Server '" + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + " : " + socket.getPort() + "'");
            updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread1("Connection Established !"));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            Log.d("debug", "unknown host: " + e1.getMessage());
            updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread1("Unknown Host error !"));
            //e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d("debug", "I/O error: " + e1.getMessage());
            updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread1("I/O error !"));
            //e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            Log.d("debug", "Exception error: " + e1.getMessage());
            updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread1("Exception error !"));
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have enabled the internet permissions also

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
```

Comment: Which IOException? You should post the logcat.

Comment: 'part of the android code where this error is seen'. You should exactly tell which statement.

Comment: 04-17 15:42:54.070    4948-4948/com.nmithun.socketcommclient D/mithun﹕ Fn : openSocketConnection
04-17 15:42:59.090    4948-5037/com.nmithun.socketcommclient D/mithun﹕ I/O error: failed to connect to /10.55.111.28 (port 9900) after 5000ms

Comment: `You should exactly tell which statement`. I repeat that.

Comment: Hi greenapps, the error happens in the code line 'socket.connect(inetsocketaddress, 5000);' and thus it executes the 'catch (IOException e1)' statement.

Comment: Setup details : i am using phone's internet (3G) connection to connect to the VPN by using "Junos Pulse" app which establishes the connection to the intranet. Thus at this point the "socket.connect(inetsocketaddress, 5000);" or "socket = new Socket(server_addr, server_port);"  or "socket = SocketChannel.open().socket();" commands does not establish the connection and throws the 'IOException' error. So my question is, can the socket communication work through the VPN by using phone's internet connection (2G/3G) or WIFI ?

Comment: Don't know. Please try the following: Do away with statements with  InetAddress and InetSocketAddress
Try: 
 socket = new Socket("10.51.100.100", 5000);

You can remove:
socket.connect(inetsocketaddress, 5000);

Comment: Sorry, no it does not work even with "socket = new Socket("10.51.100.100", 5000);".

Comment: `it does not work` ? I have never seen such an error message.